# how to map labels and values to a dictionary or map

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala so was wondering if anyone can help me with a function that would take an arbitrary list of labels, a delimted text string and return something like a Map or Dictionary.

```
val labels = Seq("color", "cost", "name")
val data = ("blue|$9.99|smurf")

private def getData(data:String, labels:Seq[String]) {
   val values = labels.split("|")

   //now how to map this split values with the the labels to create a nice map or dictionary 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val labels = Seq("color", "cost", "name")

val values = "blue|$9.99|smurf".split("\\|")
// Array(blue, $9.99, smurf)

val map = labels.zip(values).toMap
// Map(color -> blue, cost -> $9.99, name -> smurf)
```

Comment: Oh nice.   Why is the final toMap method called?  what do you get if you just call "zip" without "toMap" ing it?

Comment: zip will give you a list of (label, value) tuples. you have to call toMap to convert this to a map

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey zip produces a list of tuples.